# Fabric-script to make password less communication between 'n' instances

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, ssh-keys

the following is the code for generating rsa-key on one machine and copying public key to the other machine to facilitate password less communication.

```
import pexpect

def gen_rsa_key():
        child = pexpect.spawn('ssh-keygen -t rsa')
        child.expect("Generating.*:")
        child.sendline("")
        i = child.expect([".*Overwrite (y/n)?", ".*:"])
        if i == 0:
                print i
                child.sendline("y")
                child.expect(".*:")
                child.sendline("")
                child.expect(".*:")
                child.sendline("")
                print child.read()
        else:
                child.sendline("")
                child.expect(".*:")
                child.sendline("")
                print child.read()

        child.close()

def copy_rsa_key():
        servers = ["9.114.192.36", "9.114.192.40"]
        for ip in servers:
                cmd = "ssh-copy-id %s" %ip
                child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
                i = child.expect(["[Pp]assword:","Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?",".* WARNING: .*."])
                if i == 0:
                        child.sendline("passw0rd")
                        print child.read()
                if i == 1:
                        child.sendline("yes")
                        child.expect("[Pp]assword:")
                        child.sendline("passw0rd")
                        print child.read()
                else:
                        print "All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system."
        child.close()
        print i
```

I used the following fab command to run it on 2 machines.
fab -f /root/ssh_test.py -H 9.114.192.36,9.114.192.40 gen_rsa_key copy_rsa_key

The output displayed was good.. but it could not generate rsa-keys on remote machines at /root/.ssh/ . But /root/.ssh/authorised_keys got updated with the public key of other machine.

Can anyone help me on this issue.Please

Comment: It seems like you are not using fabric much, except for executing your python script. Please see [fabric documentation - execution model - defining tasks](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html#defining-tasks)

Comment: Ok, but when you run pexpect.spawn() it will simply run locally. To run things on the remote machine you have to use fabric's `run()` method or one of its cousins. Like `run("echo y | ssh-keygen -t rsa -N \"\"")`, for example